# how to make a radiobutton outside the radio group uncheck automatically when radiobutton on first radiogroup is checked?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I have a case like this, I have a tablelayout that has 4 radiogroups which each radiogroup have 2 radiobutton. how do I make 4 radiogroups synchronize with each other. When the radiobutton at radiogroup 1 is checked, the radiobutton in radiogroup 2 is unchecked?

This is my XML code :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_margin="20sp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/judulkolomtes"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/border_white">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/P"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/K"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/pernyataanhead"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/border_black">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/Rgroup1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Pradio1"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border_black"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Kradio1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border_black"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/pernyataan1"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_black"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/Rgroup2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/Pradio2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_black"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/Kradio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_black"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/pernyataan2"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/border_black">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Pradio3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_black"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Kradio3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_black"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/pernyataan3"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/border_black">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Pradio4"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_black"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Kradio4"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_black"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/pernyataan4"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I've tried using this code :

```
List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Pradio1) );
    radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Pradio2) );
    radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Pradio3) );

    for (RadioButton button : radioButtons){

        button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) processRadioButtonClick(buttonView);
            }
        });
    }

private void processRadioButtonClick(CompoundButton buttonView){

    for (RadioButton button : radioButtons){

        if (button != buttonView ) button.setChecked(false);
    }

}
```

but the results were not as I expected. when I checked the radiobutton at radiogroup 1 then I checked radiobuton in radiogroup 2. the radiobutton in radiogroup 1 became unchecked, but when I wanted to check the radiobutton again in radiogroup 1, the radiobutton could not be checked, also with radiobutton in radiogroup 2. 
is there a solution to this problem? based on my analysis, making the radiobutton false when another radiobutton is checked, it causes the radiobutton to be unable to check.

Comment: I tried the code that you've posted and it's working fine. I think you are confused while testing the app. You have added only first 3 vertical radio buttons in `radioButtons` array. Test this code only for first 3 vertical radio buttons (check ids Pradio1, Pradio2 and Pradio3) or Add all radio buttons in the array and try the code. It will work fine.

Comment: I use the firsrt 3 vertical radiobutton to try whether the 3 radiobutton works properly? but I tested the Pradio1 with Pradio2 the results when I tried to check again, the radiobutton could not be checked. but i confused 
because other people say the method works well. 
Does it because the Android version or the gradle version? I tested it on android Oreo

Comment: I tested it on oreo and it works fine. I don't know what's the issue but It may be possible that you are using 2 arrays with same name `radioButtons` (One global and one local). Make sure that you are using the same instance of the array in  `processRadioButtonClick()` method.

Comment: when you check the Pradio1, then you check Pradio2, is that possible to check Pradio1 again? because when i try it in my device, Pradio1 and Pradio2 is become unable to checked. unless i check the Kradio1 or Kradio2, then Pradio1 and Pradio2 is able to check again

Comment: ohh yes. You are right. I am facing the same issue. Let me try to solve it.

Comment: yup, that is an issue that I have encountered, because from some of the answers I have encountered, almost all of them use setchecked (false). but that makes the two radiobutton can't be clicked back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<RadioButton> radioButtons;
    List<RadioGroup> radioGroups;

    boolean flg = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RadioButton pradio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Pradio1);
        final RadioButton pradio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Pradio2);
        final RadioButton pradio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Pradio3);
        final RadioButton pradio4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Pradio4);
        final RadioButton kradio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Kradio1);
        final RadioButton kradio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Kradio2);
        final RadioButton kradio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Kradio3);
        final RadioButton kradio4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Kradio4);
        final RadioGroup rgroup1 =  (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Rgroup1);
        final RadioGroup rgroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Rgroup2);
        final RadioGroup rgroup3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Rgroup3);
        final RadioGroup rgroup4 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Rgroup4);

        radioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
        radioButtons.add(pradio1);
        radioButtons.add(pradio2);
        radioButtons.add(pradio3);
        radioButtons.add(pradio4);
        radioButtons.add(kradio1);
        radioButtons.add(kradio2);
        radioButtons.add(kradio3);
        radioButtons.add(kradio4);

        radioGroups = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();
        radioGroups.add(rgroup1);
        radioGroups.add(rgroup2);
        radioGroups.add(rgroup3);
        radioGroups.add(rgroup4);

        Log.e("JK->",""+ ((RadioGroup) pradio1.getParent()).getId());

        for (RadioButton button : radioButtons) {
            button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Log.e("JK->","JK");
                        processRadioButtonClick(buttonView);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void processRadioButtonClick(CompoundButton buttonView) {
        for (RadioGroup radioGroup: radioGroups){
            if (radioGroup.getId() != ((RadioGroup) buttonView.getParent()).getId()) {
                radioGroup.clearCheck();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## **What went wrong in your code.**

There is no way to uncheck `RadioButton` in Android. You were trying to uncheck `RadioButton` using setChecked(false). It was misbehaving in internal classes(RadioButton Class of Android) It was unchecking the radio button visually but not logically (My Own though from RadioButton behavior). That's why your code is not working.

## **Solution Explanation.**

For solving this issue instead of unchecking RadioButton using setChecked(false) i used `radioGroup.clearCheck()` which uncheck both buttons(Visually and logically both) of that particular group. I am not sure that it's a clear explanation or not. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: Thanks bro! You saved my life. I really appreciate for your help 

Comment: @SenaDwija Glad to help you :)